# Delete subdirectories named less than a pattern without using modified time

Tags: bash

I have directories with name as

./a/2015-01-01
./a/2015-08-08
./a/2015-10-12
./a/2015-12-12
./a/2016-01-31
./b/2015-01-01
./b/2015-08-08
./b/2015-10-12
./b/2015-12-12
./b/2016-01-31

How would I delete old entries that are named a date that is older than 10 days with a bash shell script?

Usually I would use find and look at the modified date, but since we have future dates which often won't be modified for a few months that is not an option in this specific scenario. I'm a bit baffled here since I can't come up with a good solution in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob nullglob

pivot=$(date -d '10 days ago' +%F) || { echo >&2 "error in date"; exit 1; }
for i in @(a|b)/*/; do
    f=${i%/}
    f=${f#*/}
    if [[ $f =~ [[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2} ]] && [[ $f < "$pivot" ]]; then
        echo rm -r "$i"
    fi
done
```

We're using `date` to get the `YYYY-MM-DD` format of the date 10 days ago (that's the `%F` modifier), and save that in variable `pivot`.

Then we loop through all the directories in directories `a` and `b` (that's what the extended glob `@(a|b)/*/` does). For each of these directories, after removing the trailing slash and the leading directory name (up to first slash), we check that we have a name of the form `XXXX-XX-XX` with the `X`'s being digits, and finally we do a string comparison with our saved pivot.

This won't remove any files, it will only echo lines like

```
rm -r a/2015-01-01/
rm -r b/2015-01-01/
```

Remove the leading `echo` when you're happy with the result and want to actually delete the directories.